# when should I use optical amplifier in fiber networks ? at which distance?

Tags: fiber

I am doing a presenatition on optical amplifier, and that would be later for work, how or when should I decide to use the amplifier ,around which distances could be used ?  if this question doesn't refer to this forum where should I ask it ?

Comment: Using the specs of the transceivers (output power, receive sensitivity), and the power budget/loss of the fiber plant, one can reasonably calculate where amps will be necessary. (If you're here asking the question, you aren't the person who should be in charge.)

Comment: there is a time when people don't know something before they know it, so clearly I a masking to learn how to do it later

Comment: thnx for telling how to calculate ,it will be practically later useful, but I want to put general info about the estimated distances for each cable type or wavelenght

Comment: Either this is a thinly veiled attempt to get others to do your homework ("presentation"), or you've been tasked with a job you are not qualified to do.

Comment: I have only asked a certain question , only saying at which distances should I use amplifier can NOT form a complete presentation, and  I am doing a course currently so this presentation is for the course, not for the Job itself...DUDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard SFP modules are commonly available for up to 100 or 120 km reach, so anything beyond that requires either special transceivers and careful engineering, or intermediate amplifiers.

You can't pump arbitrary levels of power into a fiber as there's only so much it can carry. Even then, a tiny fault may cause the fiber to burn backwards from the fault to the transmitter. (Since that can be very costly, high-power fibers are usually protected by logic circuitry that shuts down the power in the case of a signal loss on the far side, limiting the damage.)

Regarding *estimated distances for each cable type or wavelength* - actually, there's only one cable standard type and one wavelength (or WDM band) for long distance. Using other lambdas or cable types may require regeneration *well* before the mentioned reach (e.g. 10GBASE-SR w/ 850 nm over OM2 fiber has a reach of just 80 *meters*). You should be aware that there are a few other parameters limiting the reach of fiber than just amplitude.